# How to return different type in recursion function? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, return-type

I need to return for example either an integer or a Boolean in a recursive function.

An example code of my problem:

```
findInt :: [Int] -> Either Int Bool
findInt (x:xs) =
     if x == 1 then x
     else False : findInt xs
```

Then the error says *couldn't match expected type "Either Int Bool" with actual type "Int"*. But I want to check whether the element is in this list and if it does it will return the element and tell me if it's not by returning a Boolean.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you added some examples of inputs and the corresponding outputs that you expect, like `findInt [...] == ...` for various cases.

Comment: As it is, your function says “given a list of at least one element, if the first element is the integer 1, then return that integer, otherwise return a list beginning with the boolean `False` followed by the result of callling `findInt` on the remainder of the list; when given an empy list, raise an error”, which doesn’t make much sense, so it’s difficult to determine what you’re trying to do in order to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function as given has no type: `x :: Int` and `(False : _) :: [Bool]`, and these two types can't be unified (read `::` as "has a type").

Tweaked,

```
findInt (x:xs) =
     if x == 1 then Left x
     else Right False : findInt xs
```

it still has no type: `Left x :: Either Int b` and `(Right False : _) :: [Either a Bool]`, and these two types can't be unified either.

But

```
findInt :: [Int] -> Either Int Bool
findInt (x:xs) =
     if x == 1 then Left x
     else findInt xs
findInt [] = Right False
```

has a type, because `Left x :: Either Int b` and `Right False :: Either a Bool`, and these two types *can* be unified:

```
        Either Int b
        Either a   Bool
       -----------------      a ~ Int , b ~ Bool
        Either Int Bool
```

The unified type is indeed `Either Int Bool`, as the type signature specifies.

Comment: Further, since `Right x` is only used with `x=False`, the type `Either Int Bool` is more complex than needed, and should probably be replaced with `Maybe Int`, adapting the code accordingly.

Comment: @chi you meant "Maybe 1", i.e. `Bool`.

Comment: No, I really meant `Maybe Int`. The point is that `Either Int Bool` is isomorphic to `Int` plus two "special" values (`Right True, Right False`). Still, the code above only uses one special value (`Right False`), so we could remove the other (`Right True`) which is unused from the type. Hence, we get `Maybe Int`, and we can let `findInt (x:xs) = if x==1 then Just x else findInt xs ; findInt [] = Nothing`

Comment: @chi Since the only `Int` value ever returned is `1`, it could be further simplified from `Maybe Int` to `Bool`, where `Just 1` corresponds to `True`, and `Nothing` corresponds to `False`.

Comment: @4castle Ah, I now see Will's point. Thanks. I agree: it should be `Bool` then. (Somehow, I wonder if this is what the OP really wanted.)

Comment: @chi and then it is just `elem 1`. but I read the question narrowly, as part of the OP's general process of learning the *language*. mastering the library can come later.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a look at the [Either](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html) type, you'll see that it has two constructors, `Left` and `Right`. In order to construct a value of the `Either` type, you need to use one of the constructors. e.g.

```
if x == 1 then Left x
```

Specifically, `Left` is used to construct the first type of the Either type (`Int` in this case), and `Right` is used for the second type (`Bool` in this case).

Comment: Ahhh thank you for pointing that out! But then now I have another error which also doesnt match the expected type

Couldn't match expected type ‘Either Int Bool’
                  with actual type ‘[Either a0 Bool]’

Comment: The problem is probably related to the fact that findInt's signature says it returns a single value, but in practice it can return a list (on the else line).

Comment: I rolled back since I've posted my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you never use `True` in your output, your use of `Either Int Bool` is isomorphic to `Maybe Int`:

```
a2b :: Either Int Bool -> Maybe Int
a2b (Right x) = Just x
a2b (Left x) = Nothing

b2a :: Maybe Int -> Either Int Bool
b2a (Just x) -> Right x
b2a Nothing -> Left False
```

As such, I would just use `Maybe Int` to simplify your function.

```
findInt :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
findInt [] = Nothing
findInt (x:xs) = if x == 1 then Just x else findInt xs
```